# Can't import Netflix Zuul in Intellij Idea

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, intellij-idea, netflix-zuul

I am trying to follow a tutorial and build an API Gateway for my microservices. However when I write `@EnableZuulProxy` above the main method, IntelliJ can't find the annotation. I have cloned a GitHub repo from [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/routing-and-filtering/#initial) official Spring Boot tutorial and there it works. I don't know why in my other project the dependency can't be resolved. Please help!

My Main Class;

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EnableEurekaClient;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.EnableZuulProxy;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaClient
@EnableZuulProxy
public class GatewayServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GatewayServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Their Main:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.EnableZuulProxy;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import com.example.routingandfilteringgateway.filters.pre.SimpleFilter;

@EnableZuulProxy
@SpringBootApplication
public class RoutingAndFilteringGatewayApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(RoutingAndFilteringGatewayApplication.class, args);
  }

  @Bean
  public SimpleFilter simpleFilter() {
    return new SimpleFilter();
  }

}
```

My `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.6.1'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'xx.xxxxx'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/milestone' }
}

ext {
    set('springCloudVersion', "2021.0.0-RC1")
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Their `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.7.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.10.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    set('springCloudVersion', "Hoxton.SR9")
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

I have tried Invalidating cache.

Comment: If you look in the IDEA "External Libraries" tree in the "Project" pane, do you see  zuul?

Comment: @tgdavies no, i do not

Comment: Does IDEA understand that your project is a gradle project?

Comment: Yes it does, this is in one module. I can build other modules fine

Answer (score 3):

`spring-cloud-dependencies` does not have Zuul version defined. I had a similar issue when we upgrade the spring boot version in our project.
Please try pinning the version to some of the zuul releases,

```
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul:2.2.10.RELEASE'
```

Another bad experience I had during the upgrade was due to incompatibility with recent versions of Spring boot `>2.5.x`. I had to use the latest from `2.4.x` for my project.
This is the exception you will see during a request:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.lang.String org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.error.ErrorController.getErrorPath()
```

Spring has removed the method getErrorPath() after 2.5.x.
This is the full stack trace

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.lang.String org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.error.ErrorController.getErrorPath()'
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1082)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.servlet.TracingFilter.doFilter(TracingFilter.java:89)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.autoconfig.instrument.web.LazyTracingFilter.doFilter(TraceWebServletConfiguration.java:114)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1722)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.lang.String org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.error.ErrorController.getErrorPath()'
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.web.ZuulHandlerMapping.lookupHandler(ZuulHandlerMapping.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.getHandlerInternal(AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.java:152)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMapping.getHandler(AbstractHandlerMapping.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.getHandler(DispatcherServlet.java:1261)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1043)
    ... 47 common frames omitted
```

Comment: "spring-cloud-dependencies does not have Zuul version defined" because Zuul is no longer supported. Spring Boot currently suggests you should migrate to cloud gateway from Zuul.

Comment: From what I can tell, Spring MVC is not compatible with Spring Cloud Gateway; I guess it's not new and exciting enough, and they can't change it just for the sake of changing it.